# Very complicated Java HelloWorld app

Tags: java, object-oriented, inheritance, interface, polymorphism

This program attempts to shows the basic concepts of inheritance and polymorphism.  In what ways could the code be modified to better demonstrate those concepts? The interface, abstract class and the class are all in separate files.

**Greeting Interface**

```
interface Greeting {
    void sayHello(String greeting, String name);
}
```

**Abstract Hello Class**

```
abstract class Hello {
    String name;
    String greeting;
    public abstract void setName(String name);
    public abstract void setGreeting(String greeting);
    public abstract String getName();
    public abstract String getGreeting();
}
```

**Class that says "Hello"**

```
public class Test extends Hello implements Greeting {
    private String name;
    private String greeting;

    public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    }
    public void setGreeting(String greeting) {
    this.greeting = greeting;
    }
    public String getName() {
    return name;
    }
    public String getGreeting() {
    return greeting;
    }
    public void sayHello(String g, String n) {
    System.out.print(g + " " + n);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Test t = new Test();
    t.setGreeting("Hello");
    t.setName("World!");
    String h = t.getGreeting();
    String w = t.getName();
    t.sayHello(h,w);

    }
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say how to improve the code, when it is complicated for the sake of being complicated. What aspirations do you have? Multilingual greeters? Something that can say goodbye?

Comment: I don't have any aspirations to actually use this code for anything other than maybe an example in a blog post about *Inheritance* and *Polymorphism*.  The code is purposely complicated to demonstrate those concepts. I am looking for ideas to make the code prettier or more elegant.

Comment: I don't think this shows a good example of polymorphism, considering the interface is effectively unused: nothing is taking or returning a `Greeting`.

Comment: The interface is used.  The class Test implements the Greeting interface and overrides the `sayHello()` method.  If it didn't, the code for class Test would not compile.  If you're saying that Greeting is a bad name for the interface, I think I see your point.

Comment: No, not that it's a bad name. When I'm saying "unused", I'm saying that the interface is not used as method parameter, not used as a return-type, [not programed to](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface). Even `Test t = new Test();` doesn't use it and could be `Greeting t = new Test()`.

Comment: If you created a reference of the *type* Greeting you couldn't use is for anything.  Interfaces and Abstract classes can't be instantiated.

Comment: Yes, but if you remove `implements Greeting`, it actually changes nothing to the program and everything still works as-is. That is because, even though the class `Test` implements the interface, the fact that it implemented it is not used.

Comment: @JimFerguson "If you created a reference of the type Greeting you couldn't use it".  That's not correct at all, in fact there is really no benefit to interfaces except that you can make references of those types.  A reference of type Greeting could refer to any type that implements Greeting, allowing you to abstract away the implementation details.  For example, if you want to expose a collection, you might return the Collection or Iterable interface, because the user of your class shouldn't know - or care - what kind of collection it is.

Comment: @PMV   You're right.  I guess I didn't think that through.  Since interfaces are sort of super classes, a reference of type Greeting would be an implicit cast?

Answer (score 2):

Your example implementation is not good enough. It's not very complicated at all, as you suggest with the title; rather, it is really simple.

The `Hello` abstract class is not needed. There is no reason why a class (like a `WelcomeEmailContentBuilder` or something of the sort) should want to extend `Hello` - something like a `WelcomeEmailContentBuilder` might already be extending a `ContentBuilder` or a `EmailContentBuilder`. You are abusing the is-a relationship.

Consider this rewrite of your code:

```
interface Greeting {
    void sayHello(String greeting, String name);
}


public class Test implements Greeting {

    public void sayHello(String greeting, String name) {
        System.out.print(greeting + " " + name);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Greeting g = new Test();
        g.sayHello("Hello", "World!");
    }

}
```

This code is just as functional as your original code. But it's both way shorter and doesn't muck about with an abstract class that you don't need. It also makes use of the `Greeting` interface for a variable - showing off that you can call functions on objects if you only have an interface.

As for making your code actually show off the use of inheritance and polymorphism, that's up to you to figure out.

Comment: I was trying to demonstrate inheritance using the abstract class and polymorphism using the interface.  It seems your example demonstrates both using only the interface.

Comment: @JimFerguson Inheritance needs abstract classes or default methods (you inherit implementations). Try using `Comparable` (java.lang.Comparable) to demonstrate polymorphism, and use abstract classes to compare, say, apples and oranges (both inheriting the compareTo method from their Fruit base class

Comment: That idea would be a good demonstration of the concepts.  But I wanted the end result of the program to be "Hello Word!" to standard output.  "Hello World!" output could be used to illustrate almost all the basic concepts and constructs of Java.  For example, there are at least 8 ways to demonstrate *scope* with the end result being "Hello World!".  Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: @JimFerguson I strongly suggest you don't try to force "Hello world" as result.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Pimgd noted](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/145633/71574), your `Hello` class doesn't contribute anything.  If you remove it, everything works.

Another problem is that it's unclear why you would name the primary method of a `Greeting` to be `sayHello`.  This is particularly confusing since you have a class named `Hello`.  Why not just `say`?

Why are you instantiating an abstract `Hello` as `Test`?  The name `Hello` seems overly concrete for that.  And `Test` doesn't indicate an extension of `Hello` to me.

Consider something like

```
public interface Statement {
    public void say(String name);
}

public abstract class Greeting implements Statement {

    protected final String greeting;

    protected Greeting(String greeting) {
        this.greeting = greeting;
    }

    public String getGreeting() {
        return greeting;
    }

    public void say(String name) {
        System.out.format(greeting, name);
    }

}

public class Hello extends Greeting implements Statement {

    public Hello() {
        super("Hello, %s.");
    }

}

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         Statement hello = new Hello();
         hello.say("World");
    }

}
```

Now each of the classes does something.  If you want to make this clearer, you could add additional greetings or other implementations of `Statement`.

I also think that this taxonomy fits better.  It doesn't entirely convince me, but then this is a toy problem that could be solved with a one liner.  I do think that this better fits the constraints (must say "Hello, World." and must have an interface and abstract class).

There is probably a better name for `Statement` that would include the concept of a `name` parameter.  English.SE or ELL.SE might be better suited to help with that.

By making `name` a parameter of `say`, we no longer make a `Greeting` only work for one person.  We also avoid breaking thread safety, although this example won't exhibit that.

I find it rather bizarre that you call getters on an object in order to call a method related to the object.  That's exactly why we have objects, so as to encapsulate that kind of logic.  So I prefer this version, that doesn't require that kind of behavior.

I'd avoid trying to jam a demonstration of setters into this as well.  They don't really fit this model.  There's nothing to set in "Hello, World" except the `name`, and that really seems too localized.

Comment: The point of the exercise is to illustrate.  I agree the names are a little "wonky."  But, the setters and getters are used to show that the first concrete subclass of an abstract class must implement all abstract methods.